# Что вернет SELECT если под условие ничего не подходит

Tags: sql-server, phpmyadmin

Если мы у нас есть запрос:

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=request.form.post("username"))
```

Который ничего не должен вернуть, то он будет возвращать NULL или еще что-то?

Comment: нет, он не вернет `null`, он вернет "таблицу" с 0 строк

Comment: Почему вы просто не выполнили этот запрос на sql-server'е и не посмотрели что вернул бы вам запрос?

Comment: Все разобрался спасибо)